# Nothing is static, though apparently I can't access a non-static void

Tags: java, string, split

Neither my void nor identifier is static, but the String.split() method is giving me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method split(String) from the type String

at cal.scan.ScanningForType.Scan(ScanningForType.java:17)
at cal.scan.ScanningForType.Print(ScanningForType.java:30)
at cal.Cal.main(Cal.java:9)
```

Also, here's my two classes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanningForType {

    private int a, b;
    private String[] numsI;
    private String num1, num2, nums;

    private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void Scan(String type) {
        if(type == "Addition") {
            System.out.println("What two nums?");
            nums = sc.nextLine();
            numsI = String.split("");
        } else if(type == "Subtraction") {
            System.out.println("What two nums?");
        } else if(type == "Multiplication") {
            System.out.println("What two nums?");
        } else if(type == "Division") {
            System.out.println("What two nums?");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not yet supported - will be soon");
        }
    }

    public void Print() {
        Scan("Addition");
    }

}
```

and

```
import cal.scan.ScanningForType;

public class Cal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScanningForType sft = new ScanningForType();
        sft.Print();
    }

}
```

For some reason - I can't see why - I keep getting this error that shouldn't be getting called, though java sees it fit to be called. I haven't ran into this in the past, so I don't know why java thinks that this time is different than all the other times I've used String.split().

Comment: You're invokng `split` on the `String` class, not `nums`.

Comment: Also, your string comparison will only work by chance: `type.equals("...")` instead of `==`.

Comment: @AndyTurner that fixed everything up.

Comment: @ProgrammingNub: Since this won't be useful to others in the future, I suggest just deleting it with the "delete" link under the question. (The general topic of static vs. non-static is already well-covered here.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the error

```
numsI = String.split("");
```

You're calling the split method on String class.
Change it to this:

```
numsI = nums.split("");
```